# Can/How do you modify the execution point of a Java application under Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio IDE (v1.5.1) and its Gradle debugger to step thru my Java application.  I can single-step, step-over, step-out, break, set breakpoints etc., but I cannot find a way to manually set the next instruction/statement to be executed or alter the execution flow.

Does the Android Studio Debugger provide a means to change the execution point of the target application?